# laravel query builder for array type column

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, builder

I have an array column with name followers. I need to check if the array has an specific element using orWhere. In example below, it works for user but I cannot check if the followers array contains authUser()->id.

```
->orWhere('task.user', authUser()->id)
->orWhere('task.followers', '[?]', authUser()->id)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how about orWhereIn() ?

Comment: @jakubwrona orWherIn has format orWhereIn('id', array), it is somewhat opposite?

Comment: What is an `array` column?

Comment: If your column is just a comma delimited list which seems to be the case, `whereIn` won't work.  You will need to use something like `orWhere('task.user', 'LIKE', '%,?,%', authUser()->id)` and you should also reconsider your schema design to have an extra followers table which handles this in a more elegant matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have array list of followers and you compare this array with DB column followers you use WhereIn and pass the array list. For ex.

```
->orWhere('task.user', authUser()->id)
->orWhereIn('task.followers', [1, 2, 3, ....])
```

More about where clauses in laravel follow this link:

[Laravel Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)